# App crashing on load and its not calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` at all

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am facing a strange issue in my existing project.

Since morning I m facing one strange crash from firebase.

It was working fine without any issue but since morning I am facing this issue.

**Crash:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp
>   instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be
>   initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];`
>   (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
>   (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'

It clearly says that I need to implement `FirebaseApp.configure()` in my app delegate and it was already there since the last 6 months.

**AppDelegate Code:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as? MessagingDelegate
        self.getRegisterForRemoteNotifications(application)
        return true
    }
```

you guys can see Firebase Configure already called in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` still facing crash issue on app launch.

And I observed that my appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method not calling and its crashing my app.

Edit:

Viewcontroller code:

```
var authUI: FUIAuth!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        authUI?.delegate = self

        if authUI.auth?.currentUser != nil {
            self.checkAdminUser()
            self.getFavPlace()
        }

}
```

Edit2:

Crash Stacktrace:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp
>   instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be
>   initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];`
>   (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's
>   `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
>   (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e **exceptionPreprocess + 350  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188     3   Herrd
>
>   0x000000010559e826 +[FIRAuth auth] + 118  4   Herrd
>
>   0x00000001054fe84d
>   $s5Herrd23TopicNewsViewControllerC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfc + 605    5 
>   Herrd                               0x00000001054feaa3
>   $s5Herrd23TopicNewsViewControllerC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfcTo + 51   6
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cf7268
>   -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2427   7   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d872 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744   8
>
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753db19
>   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1423   9   UIFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff4753d57d -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251  10 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cf6531
>   -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 298    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a0e65d
>   -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1419     12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4795cc16 -[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 65    13 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d872
>   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744    14  UIFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff4753db19 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1423    15 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d57d -[UINibDecoder
>   decodeObjectForKey:] + 251    16  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00007fff47cf6531 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal)
>   _decodeObjectsAndTrackChildViewControllerIndexWithParent:forKey:] + 298   17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a0e65d
>   -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1419     18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4793fbed -[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 65    19 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cf7268
>   -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2427   20  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d872 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744   21 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d57d -[UINibDecoder
>   decodeObjectForKey:] + 251    22  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00007fff47cfb56f -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 125    23 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d872
>   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744    24  UIFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff4753db19 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1423    25 
>   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff4753d57d -[UINibDecoder
>   decodeObjectForKey:] + 251    26  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00007fff47cf6336 -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal)
>   _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 450   27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cf90a5 -[UINib
>   instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1145     28  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00007fff481f8f24 -[UIStoryboard
>   __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:]
>   + 279     29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff481f8dcf -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:]
>   + 97  30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48091ebf -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 167  31  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092473 -[UIApplication
>   _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 274     32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48090dff -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 964    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c576d -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer
>   completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122   34 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cb44c1
>   _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83    35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c627f __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer
>   _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke
>   + 198     36  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c5c8e -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 296    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c60ac
>   -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 818   38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c5941 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345   39 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c9f3f
>   __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2
>   + 178     40  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bd8c83 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 865     41  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00007fff47cd2dff
>   _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240   42  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c9c5a
>   __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke
>   + 153     43  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47cd2d02 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84   44  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff477c9ac8 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
>   + 381     45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff476206e7 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke +
>   657   46  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4761f26c
>   -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248  47  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47620411
>   -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210    48  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4808f599
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 535     49 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47bfa7f5
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361   50 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365d6165 -[FBSSceneImpl
>   _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 442     51  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc4d8
>   __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154
>   + 102     52  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365e0c45 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220  53  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff365fc169
>   __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 355     54  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a31dd48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8     55  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a320cb9 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300  56 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662237e
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30     57  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662206c
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441  58  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff3662257b
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22  59  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4471
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   60  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd439c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76     61  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd3b74 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180  62  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff23bce87f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263  63  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438     64  GraphicsServices
>   0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65   65  UIKitCore
>   0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621   66  Herrd
>   0x000000010552eb0b main + 75  67  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1  68  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Any help or guidance much appreciated!

Comment: Where and how do you initialize your FIRAuthinstance? Can you think of any changes you made in your code recently, involving FIRAuth?

Comment: In my first viewcontroller I am using `var authUI: FUIAuth!` like this.

Comment: No I dont think so I used or update something like `FIRAuth`.

Comment: Hm, ok. The error massage tells you there’s something wrong with your auth initialization. Can you perhaps post some of that code?

Comment: In your initial viewController that is

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace of the crash? It is possible that you are somehow using firebase before your app is loaded. May be you have some static object that uses it?

Comment: added both details in question.

Comment: Sorry, beats me this one. Good luck!

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far? I had a similar error before, but I can't quite remember how I fixed it. Have you uninstalled and reinstalled your podfiles yet?

Comment: yes I have already done POD reinstall and try to clean Xcode cache and derived data still no luck at all.

Comment: @CodeChanger did you manage to solve this? I personally can’t make much of the stacktrace I’m afraid

Comment: Can you clarify what this means *And I observed that my appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method not calling*? Does it mean that function isn't being called at all or does it mean your app is crashing *before* it's called? Also, if you add a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` on this line `authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()` does your app crash before or after that?

Comment: its crashing before ViewDidLoad() call and didFinishLaunchingWithOption also not calling and its crashing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found why my app is crashing and not calling `appDidFinshLaunching()`.

Its due to one of the `TabViewController` tries to getting Current user detail before `FirebaseApp.configure()` called from app delegate.

its directly define as below.

```
let user = FIRAuth().auth.currentUser
```

due to this, it's crashing.

I put it under `viewDidLoad()` method and now the app is working fine without any crash.

Thanks to every one for the quick reply and guide me on this.

Hope this info will help others!